# How to use If/Else on table to select default value

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements, xmltable

I am having trouble using the if/else conditional in xsl. In my code snippet below, I have a table that is getting its values from a database value. Initially, my code looked like

```
<fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//ROWSET3_ROW">
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select = "MODIFICATION_NUMBER" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select = "STATUS_DATE" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>   
.  
.
....
```

Where MODIFICATION_NUMBER, STATUS_DATE, and other attributes come from an xml sheet:

```
<ROWSET3>
<ROWSET3_ROW>
  <MODIFICATION_NUMBER>0</MODIFICATION_NUMBER>
  <SURVEY_JOB_STATUS_ID />
  <STATUS_DATE>5/13/2008</STATUS_DATE>
  <STATUS_NOTES />
```

In some cases, there are null values in the database for these values, so I was trying to put a conditional on those columns that dont have values. So, if the selected value is NULL, then put a random character there, such as '-'. My code doesn't seem to be working

```
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select = "30" />
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test = "STATUS_NOTES != ''">
                                                <xsl:value-of select = "STATUS_NOTES"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:value-of select = "blank" />
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                                </xsl:choose>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
```

This is what I tried to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `value-of select="blank"` will insert the value of the first child element of the current mode that is named `blank` (or the empty string in the more likely case that there is no such element). If you want the literal string "blank" use `xsl:text` instead, or just `<xsl:otherwise>blank</xsl:otherwise>`

Comment: If the OP wants to use '-', he would need to write `<xsl:value-of select = "'-'" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test = "STATUS_NOTES">
        <xsl:value-of select = "STATUS_NOTES"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select = "blank" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This will work if `STATUS_NOTES` is an empty element. If it can also contain an empty string, you can use `test="not(normalize-space(STATUS_NOTES) = '')"`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select=
      "Concat(STATUS_NOTES, substring('blank', 6 - 5*boolean(STATUS_NOTES)))"/>
```

**The above one-liner uses the fact that by definition**:

```
number(true()) = 1
```

**and**

```
number(false()) = 0
```